# Is there a better way to grep a large file and come out of execution when string is matched?

Tags: shell, grep, weblogic

Need a proper grep functionality to start grepping from the time the script is executed.

I am working on a script for automaton restart of a weblogic server. 
My script uses a line of code which will keep grepping for a string and if it is found in the logs, it will execute the next set of commands.

There is a cluster of 2 servers : 1 admin and 2 managed (Node2 and Node1).

Desired pattern is, 
Stop N2, Start N2, Stop N1, Start N1

```
#startN2
nohup sh startstopAIA2.sh start > N2Start.out &
sleep 1s
until fgrep -q "accepting" /path/logs/AIAPPD2D_SOA2.out; do sleep 1;
done
sleep .5s
echo "N2 is running. Proceeding to restart N1"

#stopN1
```

Now, the AIAPPD2D_SOA2.out is a mammoth of a file and hardly gets rotated. Also, when the 'until fgrep' part sees the existing 'accepting' string from previous restart, it proceeds with restart of N1 which should wait until N2 is completely up.

---

The log file is stamped with this piece.
"SOA Platform is running and accepting requests
"

It would be great if my 'grep until' can start grepping the file from the instance its executed and not for the entire file.

Comment: Why not rename the old file before you attempt the stop/restart/whatever cycle?

Comment: I tried that, but as soon as I rename the out file, the logs are written to a .nfs file and even upon creating a same file as previous name, it doesnt write the logs to it. :(

Comment: You need to rename the file when the processes are stopped. When this is a problem, consider a logfile with a date/timestamp in it. The last file should be small and no old `accepting`.